# Percentage of Russell 2000 stocks listed on NYSE and Nasdaq?

Tags: nasdaq, nyse

Is there a way to find out how many of the Russell 2000 stocks are listed on the NYSE and how many on the Nasdaq?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet might be to find lists of the companies on each exchange and cross-reference them with a list of the companies on the Russell 2000. It shouldn't be too hard to write a little script in python or something that does the comparison for you.

It appears that nasdaq.com has a tool that allows you to download csv lists of the stocks listed on the Nasdaq, NYSE, and AMEX exchanges.

http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/company-list.aspx

Comment: Sounds good; I can do that. I was just curious if the data was out there and I had overlooked it.